# plotting 2 .dat files, string file handle error

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I am trying to plot data from two .dat files on the same plot.
When I try, I am getting an error message.  I show exactly where it comes from below in the code.  It has to do with a string or file handle.  I am very new to python and do not know how to fix this.

I import both of my .dat files, they are both files with 2 columns.
Then I define the name of my x,y axes with a specified font size, then do the same for the title.  I then try to plot the two .dat files on 1 plot.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

#unpack file data

dat_file = np.loadtxt("file1.dat", unpack=True)
dat_file2 = np.loadtxt("file2.dat", unpack=True)

plt.xlabel('$x$', fontsize = 14)
plt.ylabel('$y$', fontsize = 14)
plt.title('result..', fontsize = 14)

plot1 = plt.plotfile(*dat_file, linewidth=1.0, marker = 'o') #error message from this line
plot2 = plt.plotfile(*dat_file2, linewidth=1.0, marker = 'v') #error message from this line

plt.plotfile([plot1,plot2],['solution 1','solution 2'])

plt.show()
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to plot with `plot` function:

```
...
plot1 = plt.plot(*dat_file, linewidth=1.0, marker = 'o', label='solution 1') 
plot2 = plt.plot(*dat_file2, linewidth=1.0, marker = 'v', label='solution 2') 
ax = plt.gca()
ax.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

`plotfile` requires to set a delimiter (default is ',') and filename not arrays, you have to write like this:

```
plot1 = plt.plotfile("file1.dat", linewidth=1.0, marker = 'o', delimiter=' ', newfig=False,  label='solution 1')
plot2 = plt.plotfile("file2.dat", linewidth=1.0, marker = 'v', delimiter=' ', newfig=False,  label='solution 2') 
plt.title("Result")
plt.xlabel('$x$', fontsize = 14)
plt.ylabel('$y$', fontsize = 14)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

`newfig=False` controls plot data on a new figure or not.

Comment: Thank you, let me go through all the details!  I really appreciate it.  If I have questions I will post here.

Comment: Everything is working and I can follow what you did.  Thanks a lot for the explanation and help on this.